# Trying to make HTTP Post request with a body using Ruby HTTP start block

Tags: ruby, http, post, http-post

I'm trying to make a POST request with basic oauth and a body param.

```
response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: true) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
  request['Authorization'] = 'ACCESS_CODE'
  request.body = {
    to:       to,
    subject:  subject,
    text:     text,
    api_type: 'json',
    uh:       @modhash
  }.to_json
  http.request(request)
end
```

It returns a

`<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>`

so I know the oauth is working but the body param is not getting passed into the request because it is returning this error

`[".error.NO_USER.field-to"]], ["please enter a username"]]`

I checked all the data values in the body hash and none of them are null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `set_form_data` method to set your POST body:

Here is an example [from the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html):

```
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request.set_form_data('from' => '2005-01-01', 'to' => '2005-03-31')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been searching for a while and saw the same method but I passed in a hash variable rather than the hash itself

Comment: Technically the two work the same. You can do `set_form_data({'from' => '2005-01-01', 'to' => '2005-03-31'})` as well.